# python reduce method works with length of 2 list but not with length with 3 or more

Tags: python, functional-programming

i have a set of points  like this:

```
points = [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

i want to add up the  x-components and y-components separately so i wrote this code

```
sum_x = reduce(lambda a, b: a[0] + b[0] ,points)
sum_y = reduce(lambda a, b: a[1] + b[1], points)
```

if i have only 2 points it works but if i add any more points then i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linear-regression.py", line 29, in <module>
    sum_x = reduce(lambda a, b: a[0] + b[0], points)
  File "linear-regression.py", line 29, in <lambda>
    sum_x = reduce(lambda a, b: a[0] + b[0], points)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 3):

Your accumulator should be an integer, not a list. You can initialize it with zero to get it started. If you don't initialize it, the initial value will be the first value in points (`[1, 1]`), which is not what you want here.

```
from functools import reduce

points = [[1, 1], [2, 3], [2, 3]]


sum_x = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b[0], points, 0)
# 5
sum_y = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b[1], points, 0)
# 7
```

Alternatively, you can do this in a single step and return a list of sums:

```
sum_x, sum_y = reduce(lambda a, b: [a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]], points)
```

Now passing the initial value in as an accumulator makes sense because the final value is a list.

Comment: it seems i didn't understand the concept right, i should've directly read the documentation so i'm gonna delete the post

Comment: Good luck. It takes a while for everyone to wrap their heads around reduce.

Answer (score 3):

Mark's answer fixes your immediate problem, but I want to point something more general out, especially since you tagged [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) (which, at its core, is about decomposing functionality into its irreducible parts). You're performing two operations that you try to treat as one. Your computation can be summarized as

1. Get the first element of each vector
2. Sum them

We can split these two steps up.

```
sum_x = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda x: x[0], points))
```

And `reduce` with addition as the operation has a name in Python: `sum`

```
sum_x = sum(map(lambda x: x[0], points))
```

Now our code reads as "get the first elements and sum them".

Answer (score 2):

why not just

```
points = [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
sum_x, sum_y = map(sum, zip(*points))
```

this works with arbitrary length list `points`.